# Would you be interested in Ice Cream Sandwich week?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We did something similar on [Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/its-aristotle-week), where we designate one philosopher each week, and each person who asks a question relating to that philosopher will be eligible to win a prize. It's gotten a positive response so far, and we could easily adapt the model for this site - that is, designate a topic each week, and everyone who asks a question about it that week is entered into a drawing to win prizes.

We could start with questions about the new operating system, Ice Cream Sandwich, then move on app week, tablet week, etc.

What do you think? If you have suggestions for other weekly topics, please leave them here as well!

**[Edit]** It seems like there is a positive response to this idea, so we'll go ahead with it starting Monday 12/19. I'll make another meta post announcing the official rules then. In the meantime, keep thinking of other ideas for future weekly topics!

Comment: That sounds like a cool idea.  Seems like it would be an easier contest to manage as well.

Comment: I like this idea. I don't think it'll cause too  many (or as many) "I'm posting *something* just to get my name in the hat"

Answer (score 7):

I was a little disappointed when I opened this and discovered that I will **not** be receiving free ice cream sandwiches all week, but this idea is neat, too.

One suggestion: Could we enforce some kind of minimum question score in order to be eligible for any drawings? Entering *everybody* would allow people to post really bad questions like "Why is ICS so AWESOME!" just to get an entry. I'd be inclined to say that only questions with a score greater than zero should be eligible (so at least *someone* else thought it was a good question).

(I also realize this would be a bit different than the Kindle Fire contest, where it appeared that people with zero score posts were entered into the drawing provided that no other answers on the question were upvoted)

Comment: There will not be any score requirements (to avoid troublesome problem of sock puppet voting/inflation). This contest will not be broadcast externally as well to avoid bad/noob questions.

Comment: I'd expect a minimum score (0?) and the question not being closed would be part of this.

Comment: @AlEverett Yes, should be 0+ and non-closed (not to contradict myself, but some standard minimum).