# It's Ice Cream Sandwich week!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This week, we’re kicking off a “Topic of the Week” series.

How it works: We will designate one topic each week, and each person who asks a question relating to that topic will be eligible to win a prize.

How to enter: [Ask a question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to the topic of the week, and tag it accordingly (this week, use the "4.0-ice-cream-sandwich" tag - see example questions [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4.0-ice-cream-sandwich)). Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win an Android accessory of your choice (under $50). Or $50 worth of ice cream sandwiches.

Choosing the topic of the week: For this first week, we decided to go with the newest Android operating system, Ice Cream Sandwich (see the discussion [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/772/would-you-be-interested-in-ice-cream-sandwich-week)). But for all following weeks we want to take suggestions from you! Leave your suggestion as an answer to this meta post, and the topic that is voted the highest at the end of each round will be the topic of the following week.

Each round will be announced Monday morning at approximately 10 am EST.

[Edit] Ice Cream Sandwich week is now over and was followed by [Tablet Week](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/784/its-tablet-week). Congratulations to Anders for winning ICS week!

Comment: Taxonomist, here I come!

Comment: Perhaps it would also be worthwhile to think about awarding the person with the most upvotes (or marked as answer) on these questions too. Otherwise it would be a lot of people only asking questions?

Comment: We thought about that, but we want to avoid sock puppet voting. This site has a pretty good answer rate, and we don't anticipate that changing because of this contest. If this contest does inspire a ton of new questions and we're lacking in answers, we can try something like you suggest for round 2. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Is this US only event?

Comment: @roxan nope, it's not restricted to the US.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested "X week!" topic:

**HTC**, **Samsung**, **Motorola**, **LG**, *etc.*: give each OEM some of the limelight, maybe a week when they release a new device. But all devices from that OEM would be part of the contest.

Comment: Thanks @AlEverett. These are great suggestions for future topics! Later today we're going to announce a new topic of the week. Hint: it rhymes with maps...

Answer (score 0):

Suggested "X week!" topic:

**Gingerbread**: by far the most used version (and for some time to come)

Answer (score -1):

Suggested "X week!" topic:

**Games**: such a popular category it's distinct from other apps at the top level of the

Answer (score -1):

Suggested "X week!" topic:

**wi-fi tethering**: because, well, a lot of people want to do it, in spite of the roadblocks their carrier places in their way