# It's tablet week!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Earlier this week, we kicked off a "Topic of the Week" series, and this week is tablet week!

How it works: Each person who asks a question about an Android tablet will be entered into a drawing to win a prize.

How to enter: Ask a question about any Android tablet and tag it [tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet) (along with any other appropriate tags - feel free to use a tag for the specific tablet as long as you also use the "tablet" tag). Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win Android accessories (your choice up to $100).

Dates: Tablet week begins now and will end Monday January 2nd at 10 am EST. We are announcing this contest a few days early because of the holidays this weekend.

**Edit**: Tablet week is now over. Congratulations to Padma Kumar for winning!

Comment: There wont be no more "Topic of the Week"? I think its a good idea but should be announced in the forum somehow.

Comment: @Lauren Thanks a lot...

Comment: yes, I got the gift that you ordered. but only less than 50 $ instead of 100 $.

Comment: That was my mistake, we recently bumped up the prize from $50 to $100 and I forgot when I notified you. I already emailed you about it, feel free to select an additional prize.