# It's Audio Week!

Tags: discussion

**This contest has ended.** There was a separate prize pool for Android Guys users. The winner from that pool is dev0, for [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19368/how-do-i-use-a-external-microphone-with-my-galaxy-nexus). The winner from the broader community is ProjectJourneyman, for [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19339/any-success-with-external-microphones-for-android-phones-or-tablets). Congratulations!

If anyone is interested in the contest details, see below.

---

Audio Week is a larger version of the [Weekly Topic Challenges](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/784/its-tablet-week), with slightly different rules and even better prizes.

To enter, ask questions related to the audio output of an Android device. Anything tagged [audio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) is eligible for this contest, but make sure you add other tags as well (for example, you can also tag the question music if applicable).

**Prizes:**

[image]

The person who asks the most viewed question will receive a Kindle Fire (or another Android tablet of similar value).

The Rules

- The contest is open to both new and current Stack Exchange and
  android.stackexchange.com  users.
- Everyone is eligible to participate regardless of geographic
  location. If you live in an area of the world where it is too
  difficult for us to ship you your prize, we’ll figure something else
  out on a case by case basis.
- The only metrics we’re using to determine winners are the number of
  page views your questions get. So ask as many good questions as you
  can, and share them using whatever means you see fit. Twitter,
  Facebook, Tumblr, Google Plus, whatever!
- There will be separate (and equal!) prizes for Android Guys readers who are participating in this contest. Check out [this post on Android Guys](http://www.androidguys.com/2012/02/06/win-a-kindle-fire-just-for-asking-an-audio-related-question/) for more details. Remember, if you heard about us from our friends at Android Guys, make sure to say in your
  profile "I am an Android Guys reader."

Dates: The contest begins Monday, February 6th at 12:01 am and goes until Friday, February 17th at 11:59 pm (UTC). Only questions that are asked within that time period will count towards this contest.

Answer (score 1):

Who won? It's almost a day since the competition ended :)

Comment: Judging by the number of views on each question, I'd say it was you :P.  That's not official, though, just be patient for Lauren to make the announcement ;) it is the weekend after all.

Comment: Okay thank you :D
Where do you see all the questions which was in the competition?

Comment: Just on the [tag page](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio), I just looked at the view count for the questions since Feb 6th.

Comment: Okay thanks, will look for it :)

Comment: The winners will be announced soon. In general, it takes us a few days to tabulate results, so when a contest ends on a Friday you can expect to see winners on Monday or Tuesday.

Comment: @Lauren: what do you mean by broader community, where [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19191/answering-machine-on-android)  question has made more view than question by ProjectJourneyman??

Comment: @user12295 yes, that question has more views than the one asked by ProjectJourneyman, but the two questions were in different categories (there were separate prize pools for readers and non-readers of Android Guys).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot Lauren.
I have sent you an email about my contact information. I don't know exactly how you are going to do this? Do you have the Kindle Fire at home, or are you going to order it? Because it can't be ordered from Amazon to Denmark. But it can be sent with the normal air mail directly to me.

But again thanks alot, and looking forward to be an active member on this lovely website :D

Comment: Yep, I got your email. Trying to work out shipping now. Will let you know soon!

Comment: Great... I have found a company in the States which can forward the Kindle to Denmark. I have sent a email with the details...

Comment: Hi again Lauren.
I need the invoice/receipt for the Kindle Fire from Amazon.
The company which sends it to me in Denmark, can't mail it without the invoice/receipt for the customs.

Could you send me a copy of it to my mail?

Thanks a lot and have a great day.

Regards Simon