# Character encoding issue on the main page

Tags: bug, status-completed

Concerns [this meta question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/834/its-audio-week) which has a `'` in the title. It renders properly everywhere, except in the small box on the main page that direct people to visit the meta.

Screenshot with obligatory red free-hand circles:

[image]

Unlikely to be a browser issue, I see the same on Chrome 18.0.1025.33 and Firefox 11.0, both on Win7/x64.

Comment: I saw the same just now too, Firefox 9.01 on Win7 Sp1 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be fixed (can somebody else confirm?):

[image]

I see what you did there, you crafty, crafty devs -- you scrambled to fix it silently without ever adding it to the bug database, in the hopes that nobody would notice. Well, guess what -- we're still on to you! :-)

**Edit:** Looks like this [has been complained about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123181/visit-meta-links-are-incorrectly-escaped) on MSO too.